# Add tuple values to dict if one value is a key in the dict

Tags: python, pandas

So I have been stuck on this for a while now.
My data looks as follows:

```
 Initialer  Start uge  Start dag Start tid  End uge  End dag   End tid
0      MBAU         18          3  09:00:00       18        5  12:00:00
1      MBAU         22          2  14:00:00       22        2  15:00:00
2      MBAU         13          4  09:00:00       13        4  10:00:00
3      AMPE         14          1  12:00:00       14        1  13:30:00
4      AMPE         26          6  09:00:00       27        2  22:00:00
```

I am trying to generate a dictionary with the 'Initialer' as keys and the values should consist of two tuples or lists, one containing the"Start"-columns and one containing the "End"-columns.
Like this  `{ 'Initialer': [(Start uge, Start dag, Start tid), (End uge, End dag,  End tid)] }`
:

```
{'MBAU': [[(18, 3, 09:00:00), (18, 5, 12:00:00)],
          [(22, 2, 14:00:00), (22, 2, 15:00:00)],
          [(13, 4, 09:00:00), (13, 4, 10:00:00)]],

 'AMPE': [[(14, 1, 12:00:00), (14, 1, 13;30:00)],
          [(26, 6, 09:00:00), (27, 2, 22:00:00)]] }
```

However, I am strugling getting it right. I have tried generating two lists of tuples containing the start columns and end columns respectively:

```
start_tuple = self.u_data[['Initialer','Start uge', 'Start dag', 'Start tid']].apply(tuple, axis=1).values
>>> 
[('MBAU', 18, 3, datetime.time(9, 0))
 ('MBAU', 22, 2, datetime.time(14, 0))
 ('MBAU', 13, 4, datetime.time(9, 0))
 ('AMPE', 14, 1, datetime.time(12, 0))
 ('AMPE', 26, 6, datetime.time(9, 0))]

end_tuple = self.u_data[['Initialer','End uge', 'End dag', 'End tid']].apply(tuple, axis=1).values
>>>
[('MBAU', 18, 5, datetime.time(12, 0))
 ('MBAU', 22, 2, datetime.time(15, 0))
 ('MBAU', 13, 4, datetime.time(10, 0))
 ('AMPE', 14, 1, datetime.time(13, 30))
 ('AMPE', 27, 2, datetime.time(22, 0))]
```

I then created a dict based on unique values in 'Initialer' and tried to use list comprehension to populate it as such:

```
start_dict = {k:[] for k in self.u_data.Initialer.unique()}
(start_dict[initialer].append((x,y,z)) for initialer, x, y, z in start_tuple)
>>>
{'MBAU': [], 'AMPE': []}
```

But this returns only empty values `{'MBAU': [], 'AMPE': []}`. I have tried to research how I could do this but without any luck.
Is there a smart way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why it fails?

The reason you are getting `{'MBAU': [], 'AMPE': []}` is because `list.append()` is an inplace operation and doesn't return anything and, the `(i for i in l)` **creates a generator object instead of actually running the append operation**.

You can see what happens here instead -

```
start_tuple = df[['Initialer','Start_uge', 'Start_dag', 'Start_tid']].apply(tuple, axis=1)
start_dict = {k:[] for k in df.Initialer.unique()}

#list comprehension runs the append operation but returns None
[start_dict[initialer].append((x,y,z)) for initialer, x, y, z in start_tuple]

### Returns: 
### [None, None, None, None, None]
### But if you print start_dict

print(start_dict)
```

```
{'MBAU': [(18, 3, '09:00:00'), (22, 2, '14:00:00'), (13, 4, '09:00:00')], 'AMPE': [(14, 1, '12:00:00'), (26, 6, '09:00:00')]}
```

This means that the operation would run and return None, but the original `start_dict` object will get modified since now you are actually iterating and not creating a generator.

---

#### A modified approach with defaultdict

More inline to the approach that you have used already, but with using `collections.defaultdict`. -

```
from collections import defaultdict

init = df['Initialer'].tolist()
start_tuple = df[['Start_uge', 'Start_dag', 'Start_tid']].apply(tuple, axis=1)
end_tuple = df[['End_uge', 'End_dag', 'End_tid']].apply(tuple, axis=1)

items = zip(init, start_tuple, end_tuple)

d = defaultdict(list)

for i,j,k in items:
    d[i].append([j,k])

output = dict(d)
output
```

```
{'MBAU': [[(18, 3, '09:00:00'), (18, 5, '12:00:00')],
          [(22, 2, '14:00:00'), (22, 2, '15:00:00')],
          [(13, 4, '09:00:00'), (13, 4, '10:00:00')]],
 'AMPE': [[(14, 1, '12:00:00'), (14, 1, '13:30:00')],
          [(26, 6, '09:00:00'), (27, 2, '22:00:00')]]}
```

---

#### Another variation

You can solve in a bit shorter way using `collections.defaultdict` as -

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for _,row in df.iterrows():
    vals = row.tolist()
    d[vals[0]].append([tuple(vals[1:4]),tuple(vals[4:])])
    
output = dict(d)
output
```

```
{'MBAU': [[(18, 3, '09:00:00'), (18, 5, '12:00:00')],
          [(22, 2, '14:00:00'), (22, 2, '15:00:00')],
          [(13, 4, '09:00:00'), (13, 4, '10:00:00')]],
 'AMPE': [[(14, 1, '12:00:00'), (14, 1, '13:30:00')],
          [(26, 6, '09:00:00'), (27, 2, '22:00:00')]]}
```

Comment: Ah great, that solves it perfectly, and thank you for the explanation. Interesting to see it as a row iteration, i didn't even think of that at all.  Thank you! :)